# Ellipse object in GDK

Tags: c, gtk, drawing, gdk

In GDK there's an object called [GdkRectangle](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/unstable/gdk-Points-Rectangles-and-Regions.html#GdkRectangle) that is used to draw rectangles. Is there a similar object for ellipses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Actually, `GdkRectangle` is not used to *draw* rectangles directly, it is merely used to *specify* rectangle position.  For instance, `gdk_draw_rectangle()` doesn't even accept any `GdkRectangle` argument.  To draw an ellipse, you could use `gdk_draw_arc()`.

Note that using GDK for drawing is quite outdated.  You could use Cairo and functions `cairo_rectangle()` and `cairo_arc()` for this.

Comment: Okay, but I need to a linked list of drawn rectangles so `GdkRectangle` comes in handy. Does `GdkRectangle` have a counterpart for ellipses?

I cannot use Cairo since this is part of a school assignment where we have to build on existing code.

Comment: @Pieter: No, there is no direct analogue.  Nothing precludes you from defining your own structure, though.